# How do I know if peace is possible between the geth and the quarians?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

I'm basically trying to make peace between the Geth and the Quarians in ME3. I have imported save files all the way from ME1 and ME2.

My problem is that I couldn't select the peaceful option on Rannoch and I got a traumatizing video. Since it's been a long time since I played ME2, I'm not sure if I met all the requirements, and if I exiled Tali or not. If I start a new game from a ME2 Import, these are the choices I made:

[image: Saved the rachni queen; Rescued Ashley Williams on Virmire; Chose to save the Council; Saved Maelon's data; Kept Wrex alive on Virmire; Chose to rewrite the geth heretics; Left the Collector Base to Cerberus; Survived the suicide mission with 9 squadmates; Romanced Ashley before ME2; Romanced Tali in ME2]

The annoying thing is that it doesn't say if Tali was exiled or not, so I have no clue if this is my problem.

I read that there are conditions (below), and I´m aware of them, but is there a way to check how many "peace points" I have?

- Rewrote the Heretics (0 points)
- Destroyed the Heretics (+2 points)
- Tali is NOT exiled (+2 points)
- Tali has been exiled/You did not do the Loyalty Mission (0 points)
- Resolved Legion/Tali conflict either using the Paragon or Renegade options (+1 point)
- N7 Mission: Save the Admiral on Rannoch in ME3 (+1 point)
- N7 Mission: Destroy Geth Squadron on Rannoch in ME3 (+1 point)
- Completed Legion's Mission in ME3 (or no peace)

Comment: Was Tali an admiral in ME3 or not? If she was not exiled, she will be an admiral; if she was exiled, she'll only be a consultant or something, helping in secret.

Comment: Did you save the admiral and destroy the geth squadron on Rannoch? If you did, Tali seems to be exiled in your save. Also I'm sorry you had to see that cutscene, too sad :(

Comment: cool ;) Tali is an Admiral on ME3 \o/  so I guess she isn´t exiled, I thik the problem is that I don´t have enough rep I only have 3 bars with a bit of red, I found later that I needed 4+ I did though save the Admiral and think I destroyed the Geth on Rannoch

Comment: Legion, Tali and Admiral Koris all have to be alive, and from what I have read, Legion and Tali's loyalty missions have to be complete from Mass Effect 2.

Comment: Which platform are you playing on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's when each of these decisions is mentioned in-game:

- Rewrote/Destroyed the Heretics: After the Geth Dreadnought mission, talk to Legion, and he will briefly discuss this decision and its consequences (you may have to explore the "investigate" options to trigger the scene).
- Tali's exile: If she was exiled, it will be [discussed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oo6v3h-6-7U) when she first appears in ME3.  If she was not exiled, she will be an admiral, and there are a number of cutscenes which mention this.
- Tali and Legion surviving the Suicide Mission (not mentioned in your question): It should be obvious.  Tali won't appear at all, and not-Legion gets a [different character model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIdE0MNOiAI) and repeatedly says "we are not Legion" in dialog.
- Resolved Legion/Tali conflict: To the best of my knowledge, this is not discussed in ME3.  This is not required for peace and isn't even worth that many points; you can definitely do without it, but the loss of loyalty can interfere with the Suicide Mission.
- Other stuff: These choices are made during ME3; you should know whether you did them or not.  In particular, the side quests remain active in your journal and on the Galaxy Map until you complete Priority: Rannoch.  It is not possible to miss them except by deliberately choosing not to do them.

The following things are **blockers** for peace.  If any of these things are not true, you cannot have peace regardless of points:

- You have four bars of reputation (regardless of paragon/renegade breakdown).
- Both Tali and Legion survived ME2.  The wiki suggests but does not explicitly state that Tali must not have been exiled.
- You did the geth fighter squadrons side quest in ME3 (Legion's quest).

Answer (score 1):

You can view (and edit) most of these decisions in [Gibbed's Save Editor](http://svn.gib.me/builds/masseffect3/?C=M;O=D).  Here's a screenshot showing where a couple are located:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I assume this only works on PC? In which case you should check what platform the asker is playing on.

Comment: @DCShannon It only runs on PC but can edit OP's Xbox 360 save too, just not PS3 saves.